# SQL - calculating hours since the earliest date in a partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL code:

```
select
    survey.ContactId,
    survey.CommId,
    survey.CommCreatedDate,
    survey.CommIdStatus,
    br.[Value],
    null as HoursPastSinceFirstActiveSurvey,
    row_number() over (partition by survey.ContactId order by survey.CommCreatedDate desc) as [row]
from
    Survey_Completed survey
inner join
    Business_Rules br on br.Name = 'OPT_OUT_TIME'
where
    survey.CommIdStatus = 'Active'
```

Which produces the following result set:
[image]

What I need help with is filling out `HoursPastSinceFirstActiveSurvey`.  The logic here should be as follows:

Calculate the total number of hours that has passed since the earliest (by CommCreatedDate) record in the partition for consecutive (by day) records.  In order to address the "consecutive" part, I was thinking perhaps it might be possible to add to the partitioning logic to only partition if the days are consecutive.  I'm not entirely sure if that's possible though. So for example, look at the last two records. They are grouped as a partition and the dates are consecutive and the earliest date/time on this partition is Nov 11 2020 12:00 AM.  So I would want to perform the following in order to populate `HoursPastSinceFirstActiveSurvey` for these two records:

Today's date minus Nov 11 2020 12:00 AM.

This would be the value for those two records in the partition for `HoursPastSinceFirstActiveSurvey`.  I am not sure where to even start with this!!  Thank you all.

Comment: TSQL supports `first_value` and `last_value` over a partition. Grab those and subtract.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve for this by the following query. Feedback is entirely WELCOME!

```
select
    Q2.ContactId,
    min(Q2.CommCreatedDate) as MinDate,
    max(Q2.CommCreatedDate) as MaxDate,
    Q2.Consecutive,
    datediff(hour, min(Q2.CommCreatedDate), max(Q2.CommCreatedDate)) AS HoursPassed
from
    (select
        Q1.ContactId,
        Q1.CommId,
        Q1.CommCreatedDate,
        Q1.CommIdStatus,
        Q1.[Value],
        Q1.Consecutive,
        Q1.[row],
        Q1.countOfPartition
    from
        (select
            survey.ContactId,
            survey.CommId,
            survey.CommCreatedDate,
            survey.CommIdStatus,
            br.[Value],
            CAST(dateadd(day,-row_number() over (partition by survey.ContactId order by survey.CommCreatedDate), survey.CommCreatedDate) as Date) as Consecutive,
            row_number() over (partition by survey.ContactId order by survey.CommCreatedDate desc) as [row],
            count(*) over (partition by survey.ContactId) as countOfPartition
        from
            Survey_Completed survey
        inner join
            Business_Rules br on br.Name = 'OPT_OUT_TIME'
        where
            survey.CommIdStatus = 'Active') Q1
    where
        Q1.countOfPartition <> 1) Q2
group by 
    Q2.ContactId, Q2.Consecutive, Q2.[Value]
having
   datediff(hour, min(Q2.CommCreatedDate), max(Q2.CommCreatedDate)) > Q2.[Value]
```